# I have a / between # and my section

Tags: html

I have the following:

```
<li>
    <a class="target-section1 current" href="#section1" title="SectionUno">SectionUno</a>
</li>
```

And I also have this :

```
<section id="section1" class="Section_Uno">
```

If a click on the link, the url becomes `www.mysite.com#/section1`, I have the "/" between the hash and the section and i don't know why, and moreover it doesn't do the link which is in the same page.

Comment: Are you sure you have links in the correct format? Is there any redirect (in PHP/htaccess/etc.) which can cause that?

Comment: Are there any rewrite rules enabled on your server?

Comment: Yes and i don't have php/htaccess but i have a angularJS script which doesn't change the url or the link :/
I'm on local machine for tests.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you're providing. It must be something else.

Comment: Can you provide some more info, like what you actually want to achieve from this code? Do you use any java script or jQuery?

Comment: I use a angularJS script, it's possible that angularJS read the # for something else ?

Comment: I see that it was #/section1 in angularJS because # is already use for something so with `href="#/section1"` and `id="#/section1"` it works :)